# Angular2 Can't resolve all parameters for ParamDecorator: (?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-services

**[RESOLVED]**

I'm getting Vimeo data from JS API oEmbed, so I created a service:

**video.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from "@angular/core";
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {Video} from "./video";

@Injectable()
export class VideoService {
  apiUrl = "https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url="

  constructor(private _http: Http){}

  getVideo(videoUrl:string){
    return this._http.get(this.apiUrl+videoUrl)
               .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

with the model interface `Video`:

**video.ts**

```
export interface Video {
  url: string,
  title: string,
  desc: string,
  thumbnail: string,
  player: string
}
```

After that, I injected it to `VideoGridComponent`:

**video-grid.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {Video} from './video';
import {VideoService} from './video.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-grid',
  templateUrl: './video-grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-grid.component.css']
})

export class VideoGridComponent implements OnInit {
  urls: string[] = [
    "https://vimeo.com/110217114", 
    "https://vimeo.com/175629655", 
    "https://vimeo.com/187604216", 
    "https://vimeo.com/177237096"
  ];
  videos:Video[];

  constructor(private _videoService: VideoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (var i in this.urls) {
      this._videoService.getVideo(this.urls[i])
        .subscribe(
          data => this.formatRemoteVideo(data),
          error => console.log(error),
          () => console.log('Finish get video')
        )    
    }
  }

  formatRemoteVideo(data){
    let vid:Video;
    vid.title = data.title
    vid.desc = data.description
    vid.thumbnail = data.thumbnail_url
    vid.player = data.html
    this.videos.push(data)
  }
}
```

The TS compiler done with the well result has no error. But the browser doesn't run the script and output the strange error belong to `ParamDecorator`:

```
metadata_resolver.js:499 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ParamDecorator: (?, ?, ?)
```

I researched but seem as no one met that. Where did I go wrong?

**UPDATE**
I also checked the `tsconfig.json`, it has normal values:

```
{
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
I don't know why but it runs after I had canceled the terminal `npm start` and rerun it. I think it's a compiler problem, that doesn't copy/update new declairision so it makes this error. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What's your tsconfig.json look like?

Comment: It has "emitDecoratorMetadata": true and  "experimentalDecorators": true,

Comment: It works for me. Could you please share your code somewhere ?

Comment: thank you @yurzui The problem is gone. I don't know why but It works now. I have updated the question for resolved it.